# get comments to facebook ad

Tags: facebook-graph-api, comments

We have a solution where we use facebook graph API to handle the company fb-page for our customers.
We read the comments and messages written on the page och may reply via the graph api.
So far - no problem.

Now the customer is buying ads that is pushed into the newsfeed of fb-members. These ads have the pageid as sender.
We want to access the comments that these ads generate from people.

I'm not sure how to access these comments thru the api!?

I tried with: /{page-id}/comments 
This return an error message: Tried accessing nonexisting field (comments) on node type (Page)

Or do I need to use the Marketing API?

Anyone that can point me in the right direction?! :o

Answer (score 2):

You should use Marketing API in order to get the ads. Some thing like this:

```
        AdAccount account = new AdAccount(ACCOUNT_ID, context);
        Map<String, Object> extraParams = new HashMap<>();
        extraParams.put("fields", "creative{object_story_id},created_time,status");
        APINodeList<Ad> ads = account.getAds().execute(extraParams);
        for (Ad ad : ads) {
            String objectStoryId = ad.getFieldCreative().getFieldObjectStoryId();
            //now you can use /{objectStoryId}/comments
        }
```

I used the facebook ads java api in this Example. Here https://github.com/facebook/facebook-java-ads-sdk.

Comment: Thanks. It is as I suspected.